# 2 drawable button Horizontally without space between 2 button and onclick change drawable button color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

am new to android. i would like to have two drawable bg button Horizontally. Button1(Tour Routes) and button2(Tour Item) without space between two button and while onClick button1,i like to display blue drawable (Tour Routes) on button1 and drawable hover background on button2(Tour Items) and Viceversa.   Thank You

Here is My layout Example. I tried to create drawable xml but its not working fine.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"      
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="T"
    android:background="@drawable/btn"
    android:onClick="button1"

     />

 <Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TI"
    android:background="@drawable/btn"
     android:onClick="button2"
    />
```

Comment: Try to set `android:clipToPadding="false"` for your parent `LinearLayout`.

Comment: mention you requirement one by one in order and be clear.

Comment: Firstly, add `android:weightSum="2"` for LinearLayout

Comment: Hi,Shubh thanks for the reply,just added the Screen shot.

Comment: post ur current image and if @drawable/btn is xml post dat too

Answer (score 1):

Check with below code, you can use weightsum for the layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"      
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/update_bg_button"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_font_color" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/update_bg_button"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:text="@string/clear"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_font_color" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the update_bg_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/button_bg_color" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@color/button_fg_color" /> <!-- focused -->
<item android:state_hovered="true"
      android:drawable="@color/button_fg_color"/> <!-- hovered -->
<item android:drawable="@color/button_fg_color" /> <!-- default -->
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: How it looks in my case]

I think, you can adopt my code for you requirements (add gradient background, remove stroke, etc).

Code in layout:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbCategories"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rb_left_bg_selector"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/tab_categories"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbSort"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rb_right_bg_selector"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/tab_sort"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

rb_left_bg_selector.xml is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rb_left_selected_bg" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rb_left_unselected_bg" android:state_checked="false"/></selector>
```

rb_left_selected_bg.xml is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<solid
    android:color="@color/blue_dark"/>
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

rb_left_unselected_bg.xml is:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="-1dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/blue_dark"/>
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

It's similiar for right RadioButton.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Lets go for some simple work:

Assuming you have 2 images in your drawable folder Say: blue and grey

First Step:

```
Note: Considering first button as your default button, So set the blue image as 
      background to your first button and grey to your second button
```

How?

```
  <Button
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Tour Routes"
   android:background="@drawable/blue"     // set your blue image over here
   android:onClick="button1" />

 <Button
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:id="@+id/button2"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Tour Items"
   android:background="@drawable/grey"     // set your grey image over here
   android:onClick="button2" />
```

Second Step:

Its obvious you have implemented click listener on both buttons. just implement this

```
   button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
        }
    });
```

I am hoping its works for you and this is what you want :)

Comment: Please let me know is it works for you or not. And sorry, if i misunderstood you question.